# How to cancel response from server?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

This is my code

```
function sendMessage()
{
 if(textMessage.value!=="close")
  {
    if(searchid==="John" && login_id==="Mary" || searchid==="Mary" && login_id==="John")
       {
        webSocket.send(textMessage.value);
        textMessage.value="";
       }
   }
  else
  {         
   webSocket.close();
  }
}
```

I am making a chat application and getting response from server.Firstly the server was sending response to all the clients connected to it.But now I am converting it into one to one client based chat but the problem is if john is chatting with mary these values are placed in database and I can only one time get the data from database via scriplet when page is loaded so how to implement it when user want to chat with say dave.Then I can't get the values from database.

Answer (score 2):

I totally understand that you would like to write this by your self, but there are lots of frameworks out there that will help you with the complex stuff and let you focus on the actuall business issues to solve.

We use XSockets.NET most of the time since that is perfect for our needs.
Setting ap a one to one chat (or other scenarios) is very easy with XSockets since it is all about publish/subscribe... And you can also filter where to send messages on the server with powerful extension methods

**A simple sample chat:**
To save some time and keep it stupid and simple I will use two dropdowns where you select your name and the city you are in. So not actually 1-1, but it is so that you would get the concept.

**JAVASCRIPT/MARKUP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title></title>
                <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/XSockets.latest.js"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>

                <script>
                //viewmodel for our messages
                var vm = {
                    messages : ko.observableArray([])
                }

                //xsockets connection
                var conn;
                $(function() {
                    ko.applyBindings(vm);
                    //Connect to our controller (Chat)
                    conn = new XSockets.WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4502/Chat');

                    conn.onopen = function() {
                        //open, set city and username (for demo only)
                        conn.setProperty("UserName", $('#username').val());
                        conn.setProperty("City", $('#cities').val());

                        //listen for chatmesages
                        conn.on('chatmessage', function (d) {
                            //Add message to viewmodel
                            vm.messages.push(d);
                        });
                    }

                    //When we hit enter, send a message
                    $('input').on('keydown', function (e) {                
                        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    //Build message, we do not need to set From since the server know who I am
                            var message = { Text: $(this).val(), Time: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') };
                            conn.publish('chatmessage', message);
                        }
                    });

                    //When City or Username is changed, tell the server
                    $('#cities').on('change', function(d) {
                        conn.setProperty("City", $(this).val());
                    });
                    $('#username').on('change', function (d) {
                        conn.setProperty("UserName", $(this).val());
                    });
                });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" placeholder="type here, enter to send"/>
            <select id="username">
                <option value="steve">steve</option>
                <option value="ben">ben</option>
                <option value="tomas">tomas</option>
            </select>
            <select id="cities">
                <option value="london">london</option>
                <option value="paris">paris</option>
                <option value="tokyo">tokyo</option>
            </select>
            <div data-bind="foreach:messages">
                <h5 data-bind="text:From + ' - ' + Time"></h5>
                <div data-bind="text:Text"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**C#**

```
using XSockets.Core.XSocket;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket.Helpers;

namespace SimpleChat
{
    public class ChatMessage
    {
        public string From { get; set; }        
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }

    public class Chat : XSocketController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// My name, we set this from javascript...
        /// </summary>
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// We only send to people being in the same city, we set it from javascript
        /// </summary>
        public string City { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// A user sends a message
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="chatMessage"></param>
        public void ChatMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage)
        {
            chatMessage.From = this.UserName;
            //Send only to the client(s) being in the same city, but you can ofcourse change ot to another user only etc
            this.SendTo(p => p.City == this.City, chatMessage,"chatmessage");
        }
    }
}
```

**Summary**
The only thing I did except the code above was to create a new project and then

- Install XSockets (to start a xsockets server)
- Install XSockets.JsApi (for publish subscribe over websockets)
- Install jQuery (becasue I am lazy)
- Install Momoent.JS (for working wiht dates in javascript)
- Install knockoutjs (for modelbinding)
- Added a XSockets bootstrapper into App_Start (found under Add->NewItem->XSockets->XSockets.Web.Bootstrapper

Answer (score 1):

I guess you simply need to add  control functionality to your program:
Add two listboxes and two buttons for picking sender, receiver (search_id,log_id)

```
List <string> logins=new List<string>();
List <string> search=new List<string>();
 ........

logins.Add("John");
logins.Add("Mary");
.....
search.Add("Dave");
listBox1.Datasource=logins;
listBox2.Datasource=search;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //pick login_id
        {
            login_id_to_Compare=listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //pick searcid
        {
            searchid_to_Compare=listBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }


function sendMessage()
{
 if(textMessage.value!=="close")
  {
    if((searchid===searchid_to_Compare) && (login_id===login_id_to_Compare))
       {
        webSocket.send(textMessage.value);
        textMessage.value="";
       }
   }
  else
  {         
   webSocket.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your send message seems too simplistic.  There is not enough info for the server to route the message to the correct destination.

You would need to send along with the message the destination so your server can route the message to the correct user.

In your db you then can save the "to" and "from" and display the correct messages for only the parties involved.

You would of course have to add the fields to your chat program to select the destination.

```
function sendMessage(from, to, msg)
{
    webSocket.send("{'from':" + from + ", 'to':" + to + ", 'msg': " + msg + "}");
}
```